# Issues with Terraform GitHub Actions

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

Trying to fix and issue that broke my environment. I stopped a Terraform Apply GitHub action halfway through causing it to enter a state lock. I removed the state lock but now I am getting issues with many resources that already already existing in my environment but Terraform is still trying to create them.

i.e

```
4129│ status code: 400, request id: 29a016bd-e351-4985-91f6-8442408104eb
4130│ with module.vpc.aws_db_subnet_group.database[0],
4132│ on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 456, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "database":
4133│ 456: resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "database" {
```

A Terraform destroy doesn't work because it's looking for an output of an EKS cluster that doesn't exist since it doesn't create before the Apply errors out.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
111│ on helm-autoscaler.tf line 75, in module "cluster_autoscaler_irsa":
113│ 75:   cluster_autoscaler_cluster_ids   = [data.terraform_remote_state.infra.outputs.module_eks_cluster_id]
114│ data.terraform_remote_state.infra.outputs is object with 8 attributes
116│ This object does not have an attribute named "module_eks_cluster_id".
```

Not sure how to get out of this state nor can I manually delete every single resource in my AWS environment

Terraform destroy, removing state lock, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to go step by step, removing conflicting resources from the tfstate (`terraform state rm <resource>`) so that such resource is no longer maintained by Terraform, and then you manually delete it.

Comment: I have hundreds of resources spread across 2 broken environments it's not preferable to remove the state of say 8 objects, do another run, run into 8 more resource errors, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @squeekwal yes, that's what I just said. You need to iterate step by step, removing the conflicting resources on each iteration.